# Does being in human form help with item discovery?

Tags: dark-souls-2

What the title says :)

Also does the number of human effigies in the inventory help item discovery ?

I'm on the PC version.

Comment: I think you mean item drop rate/chance from enemies. At least, that's what it was in DS 1.

Comment: I don't know if being alive increases it, because there is no stat for that anymore like in Dark Souls 1, but the amount of human effigies in the inventory has definitely no effect on anything. The only discovery increasing items I know of are the Gold Serpent Ring, the Merchant's Hat and the Clown Hat.

Comment: @DDC Also, Prisoner's Tatters and a +1 equivalent of the Gold Serpent Ring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drops do not depend on your players humanity
You will get drops depending on your players stats
That's why when you use a rusted coin, it boosts you luck/drop stat
You get better loot for an amount of time

So nothing to do with your humanity